# Why does Listview hide text too long?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Listview hides long text.

Visual Studio, Xamarin-Forms

```
ListView x:Name="listView" Refreshing="Refresh">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
<Label Text="Text and text"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
<Label Text="Text text text text Text text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text textText text text text " />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The only way out that I found is `RowHeight = 70`
But I do not like `RowHeight = 70`, because everywhere the text is of different length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **HasUnevenRows** property to **True** and let unset the **RowHeight** property. Also set **LineBreakMode** for Label

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                   <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```